# how to create html using new lines in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

php - this works:

```
$html = "
    <div class='part partb4'>
    <img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'>
    </div>";
echo $html;
```

javascript - doesn't work:

```
let html = "    
    <div class='part partb4'>
    <img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'>
    </div>";
    $(html).insertBefore($('.part').eq(0));
```

javascript -  this works:

```
let html = "<div class='part partb4'><img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'></div>";

$(html).insertBefore($('.part').eq(0));
```

How to make the second example valid? I'm on windows, Notepad++.

Thanks.

Comment: in first js code one bracket is not close `$(html).insertBefore($('.part').eq(0);`

Comment: bracket is not close $(html).insertBefore($('.part').eq(0);

Comment: @MaheerAli, corrected, but still doesn't work

Comment: You can't do multiline like that in javascript. You need to replace `""` with `\`\`` (called template literals)

Comment: what if you try something like
let html = "<div class='part partb4'>";
html += "<img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'>";
html +=" </div>";
 $(html).insertBefore($('.part').eq(0));

I am not sure if it will work but you can give it a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding a backslash ( \ ) as the last character in the line, you can't even have a space bar behind it, because then it won't cancel the line break.

```
let html = "    
<div class='part partb4'>\
<img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'>\
</div>";
$(html).insertBefore($('.part').eq(0));
```

Comment: yeah missed that out

Answer (score 1):

For the multiline you should use a single backticks ` (shift + button before 1)

```
let html = `
  <div class='part partb4'>
<img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript 6 (ES6) introduces a new type of literal, namely template literals. They have many features, variable interpolation among others, but most importantly for this question, they can be multiline.

A template literal is delimited by backticks:

```
var html = `
  <div class='part partb4'>
<img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows strings to be split in ES6 using the backticks:

```
let html = `    
<div class='part partb4'>
<img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>`;
$(html).insertBefore($('.part').eq(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiline string thats why its not working I guess
use template literals

```
let html = `    
    <div class='part partb4'>
    <img class='imgb4' src='imgdef/01.jpg' alt='img'>
    </div>`;
    $(html).insertBefore($('.part').eq(0));
```